# Download CSS and JS using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to download content of web (CSS and JS and probably HTML) using python.

How do I download them instead of printing their names on text file?

Here's my code so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# URL of the web page you want to extract
url = "http://books.toscrape.com"

# initialize a session
session = requests.Session()
# set the User-agent as a regular browser
session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

# get the HTML content
html = session.get(url).content

# parse HTML using beautiful soup
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

# get the JavaScript files
script_files = []

for script in soup.find_all("script"):
    if script.attrs.get("src"):
        # if the tag has the attribute 'src'
        script_url = urljoin(url, script.attrs.get("src"))
        script_files.append(script_url)

# get the CSS files
css_files = []

for css in soup.find_all("link"):
    if css.attrs.get("href"):
        # if the link tag has the 'href' attribute
        css_url = urljoin(url, css.attrs.get("href"))
        css_files.append(css_url)

print("Total script files in the page:", len(script_files))
print("Total CSS files in the page:", len(css_files))

# write file links into files
with open("javascript_files.txt", "w") as f:
    for js_file in script_files:
        print(js_file, file=f)

with open("css_files.txt", "w") as f:
    for css_file in css_files:
        print(css_file, file=f)
```

How do I download them instead of printing their names on text file?

Comment: You need to request for those using "GET"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download using `requests` and extract the filename using `os.path.basename()`

```
import os

for js_file in script_files:
    fileName = os.path.basename(js_file)
    text = requests.get(js_file).text
    with open(fileName, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(text)

for css_file in css_files:
    fileName = os.path.basename(css_file)
    text = requests.get(js_file).text
    with open(fileName, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Comment: I got the following error                     `
      5     text = requests.get(js_file).text
      6     with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
----> 7         f.write(text)
      8 
      9 for css_file in css_files:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 165-169: character maps to <undefined>
`

Comment: try replace the `open()` with `with open(fileName, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:`

Comment: well, It works, How do i save those files in separate folder?

Comment: modify `fileName` variable